# Unable to load yarn application logs in Ambari

Tags: hadoop, hadoop-yarn, azure-hdinsight, ambari

I'm unable to load yarn application logs in Ambari. After clicking the link 'Resourcemanager UI' -> Application -> Application id in ambari portal, It's keep on loading the page and unable to view the output. 
However, I'm able to view yarn application logs using 'yarn logs -application .

Any leads that why I'm unable to view logs in portal.

Thanks.

Comment: Could you please share the screenshot of the error message?

Answer (score 0):

This could be the browser issue. You may try the following steps and let us know.

- Clear “Cookies and Cached data” of your browser.
- Private Mode (New InPrivate Window).
- Try in different browser.

Meanwhile, you can use the alternate methods to access Yarn application logs on HDInsight Cluster.

**Reference:** https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/hdinsight/hdinsight-hadoop-access-yarn-app-logs-linux

Hope this helps.